# Does a spritz of argon preserve wine?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas

There are wine preservation products that consist of canisters from which you blast a small amount of argon into a partially emptied bottle before shoving the cork back in. The marketing says that, because argon is heavier than air, it will settle over the surface of the wine (as long as you keep the bottle vertical) and shield the wine from contact with the air in the bottle.

With gas molecules constantly in motion and gases being thoroughly miscible, would a quantity of argon in a bottle really settle sufficiently to form an effective barrier? And how long would it take to settle sufficiently? If the argon *has* settled, would the barrier be broken and need to reform if one were to disturb it by, say, moving the bottle to another place on the shelf?

Answer (score 1):

At room temp the gasses will mix more or less uniformly. A spritz of Argon will displace some air above the wine, but don't count on gravity to shroud the wine with pure Argon based on its higher density. Diffusion dominates over gravity. At best there will be a slight concentration gradient, not a layer, at least at room temperature. Spritzing will dilute the air in the bottle but it requires multiple iterations to dilute it sufficiently. Not practical for the little cans of Argon. A waist high 40cu ft Argon cylindar at 2000psi holds about 150,000 litres of Argon at atmospheric pressure. It takes about 4.5 litres to dilute the headspace above a half filled bottle of wine by 12x, reducing oxygen by that same factor.  The tank is enough for >30,000 bottles. Get Argon or Nitrogen at local welding shop. Cost of 40cu ft cylindar, flow regulator, tubing, nozzle and gas $200-$300. Works out to about 1 cent per bottle saved.